# How to connect PDO-oci with codeigniter

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, pdo, codeigniter-3

Here is my database.php(application/config/database.php)'s code(I modify the first half to accords with my server configuration):

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => 'oci:dbname = (DESCRIPTION =
                    (ADDRESS_LIST =
                      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Server ip)(PORT =  Server port))
                    )
                    (CONNECT_DATA =
                      (SERVICE_NAME = project)
                    )
                  )',
'hostname' => 'Server ip',
'username' => 'exampg',
'password' => 'Server pw',
'database' => 'project_exampg',
'dbdriver' => 'pdo');
```

when I load database in controller($this->load->database()), I meet:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: pdo_oci_handle_factory: ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

How to solve this problem?

I have test my pdo-oci connection with these codes as follows(It can work):

```
$tns = "(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Server IP)(PORT = Server port))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVICE_NAME = project)
))";
$db_username = "exampg";
$db_password = "server pw";
try{
    $db = new PDO("oci:dbname=".$tns,$db_username,$db_password);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo ($e->getMessage());
}
```